# How to model data for in-memory processing

Tags: java, performance, architecture, data-modeling

I have a lot of static data (i.e. read only data, which is not transactional) which gets updated only once in few days.

I have to support searches on that data (api calls, not sql). So I am thinking I will just load it in Memory, and refresh the in-memory data once in a while. The RAM should not be an issue since we are on 64 bit... data can be in 2 GB to 50 GB range.

I am hoping I can process searches on the in-memory data much faster than querying a database (indexed tables as well).

Is there a certain "approach" I can take to design this in-memory data?

**UPDATE:**

My question isn't about what RDBMS / noSQLDB to use.  I want to know how to structure data in-memory when I am no longer bound by a storage mechanism.

Comment: You could use an in-memory relational database like [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/).

Comment: is that really the best approach?

Comment: I would say this depends a lot on the type of data and what sort of searches you need to support. Image searches might require a different solution than simple substring matches on purely textual data or complex relationship queries over structured data. You should add more infos about data and query types.

Comment: I am working on a relational database. Something similar to tracking inventory of a store, or storing information employees of a company.  I do have a couple of Entities that have Date-Time component to track events that take place (granularity of milliseconds).  So yes, most queries will be "search where something = "this" or something like "this%"

Comment: Why not storing it into database? Isn't it logical to use database for queries searching?

Comment: There are plenty of in-memory databases, each with their pros and cons. You should definitely study that option rather than try to implement your own...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It totally depends on what kind of data you are working with and what kind of searches you want to perform on it.

For example, with hash based structures you can not support partial word searches.

You could go for an in-memory relational db if your data is really relational (With lot of columns and relations). You can index all the searchable columns. But RDBMS is of no use, if your data is just a bunch of key value pairs or just a bunch of paragraphs.

A specific DS can not be suggested here with out the knowledge of your requirements.

I suggest you to explore data structures(like search trees, tries, hashtables), databases(like redis), search engines(like solr, lucene) to find out which suits your needs best.

Comment: The more I read about anything like Redis/Cassandra etc.. it seems they really are just key-value storage with abstractions.  Even your suggestion of indexing every searchable column, would mean there would many key-value storages (i.e. indexes).

Comment: I think it boils down to this:  1. Figure out what data you want Exact-Match Access  for (key needs to match exactly to input)  and then use some HashTable implementation.     2. Figure out what data you want "Like-Match Access"for (key can be a substring of input) and then use some Tree implementation.

Comment: come to think of it, even "Tree storage" ...  is really just a large interconnected key-value pairs.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Especially regarding Trie and Solr.

Comment: Tries allow partial searches for substrings those match the beginning of the actual string. Tries also allow you to implement "suggest as you type" kind of features.  If you wish to implement full fledged substring searches, explore suffix trees.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Redis ( http://redis.io/ ) before and it is a very fast in memory storage. As an approach, creating keys for your data helps optimizing any search and redis supports that .

If you also need any kind of data processing, you could look maybe look at Hadoop / HBase.

Comment: 1) Hadoop is on-disk, node-distributed system, the question is about in-memory, apparently single server. 2) Hadoop is about processing data, not searching. That's enough. Even Spark/Elasticsearch/cassandra are better in any way, though 99% is that they are also not best adressing the actual OP's problem.

Comment: You're right bout the processing part - Hadoop is worth mentioning only if data processing is involved.  But he does need a large set of data ~ 50GB so in memory storage might not be really the only option.

Comment: @leventov  If am designing data such that have I have keys for entities and then store key=>entity records in something like redis/cassandra, then wouldn't that be same "approach" as using an RDMS and creating bunch of indexes for each column?

Answer (score 0):

Years ago, I have used [prevayler](http://prevayler.org/) for a non-database web-application. It was incredibly fast! It uses POJOs. Easy to understand and implement.

Data structure was very simple. Think about it as a tree with a default node. Prevayler knows the root of the tree and you add your data to this tree. You can take snapshots of the tree as a backup mechanism. You can even use XML snapshots.

Prevayler was one of the very first of this kind. I am sure there are other libraries. Make a bit of a research before you decide which one to go with.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to learn how to build a hashtable?

Read up on [Binary Search Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree), read a few books on algorithm design..  Probably read [The art of computer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming).

Or use whatever Hashtable implementation that your particular language uses.

Many people are recommending databases simply because, unless your model fits into a simple hashtable model, you will end up needing a database (doing your own indexing and joining algorithms is silly).  Here is a list of [In-Memory databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_in-memory_databases) which might help you choose a path.  A lot of what you choose depends on your platform, and if you are looking to spend money.

Answer (score 0):

It mostly depends on your access patterns and how you want to deal with your data.

for example if you want fast search and getting some part of the data sorted, a red black tree data structure can be a good way to do it.
or if you want simple key-value you can use a hash table.

but implementing these data structures can be tricky and hard and many people have solved this problem several times before.

It's strongly advised to use solutions like redis or other in memory databases. 
simply DRY.